# Add name resolution dependency to systemd service

Tags: centos7, systemd

How can I make a systemd service, for example nginx, start after name resolution is successful?

```
2017/06/30 08:39:12 [emerg] 737#0: host not found in upstream "upstream.example.com" in /etc/nginx/nginx.conf:109
```

I've attempted to add a drop-in file `/etc/systemd/system/nginx.service.d/nss-depency.conf`

```
[Unit]
After=nss-lookup.target
```

However this does not help, which should be obvious, as `/usr/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service` already has `After=network.target remote-fs.target nss-lookup.target` in it.

---

I have a similar issue with rpc-gssd.

Answer (score 1):

I think the target you're looking for is [`network-online.target`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/NetworkTarget/). This should be active only after a network connection is up and usable.

Answer (score -1):

I use `nss-lookup.target` a fair bit. It seems to work for me.

I know this is a bit silly... Are you sure you ran `systemctl daemon-reload` after changing the service configuration?